# Facebook sdk 4 iOS user info email readpermissions dont work

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, sdk

I try to use the iOS Facebook SDK version 4.

i completed the login without problem,but impossible to get user email adresse using graph API. if someone have a solution for it can be very cool.

here my code, in view did load  :

```
_FBButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
_FBButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];



_FBButton.delegate = self;
```

here the method when login success :

```
- (void)loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result error: (NSError *)error{



 if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {       


    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result2, NSError *error) {

         if (!error) {
             NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result2);
         }
     }];
  }
}
```

here the result :

```
 "first_name" = Jack;
gender = male;
id = 1381385368853232;
"last_name" = Ammer;
link = "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/1381385368853232/";
locale = "fr_FR";
name = "Jack Ammer";
timezone = 2;
"updated_time" = "2015-04-02T07:26:35+0000";
verified = 1;
```

so why i can get the email adresse ?

thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

maybe the problem is caused because facebook ask user only for public profil,check the picture : why readpermissions dont work ?

[image]

Comment: found a solution to it?

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution, i dont really know why exactly but it works ! 
it's very easy, you should not initialise the Facebook Button when it added on storyboard. To solve my problem i just comment the line where i initialise the button.

```
 //facebook
 // _FBButton = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"]];

 _FBButton.readPermissions = @[@"email"];
 _FBButton.delegate = self;
```

and now all works good ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check properly you must be getting user Email address into your console.

Tried your code at my end and getting email address using FBSDKGraphRequest.

Comment: i think i dont work because when user login, API dont ask for the good permissions, look at the picture. there is only public profil

Comment: before to try with SDK v4, i tried with V3 and it's the same problem ;( i dont understand why.

Comment: can u just try passing only email as public_profile is available by default

Comment: same thing....maybe a need to set something special on facebook developer console in my apps settings ?

Comment: I am also getting email but only in simulator and its not giving on real device .

Answer (score 0):

The problem of mine is my facebook account did not have an verified email address (yes, this can happen!). please check your profile setting page.

Comment: Hi, no i tried with multiple account. that's the same problem, it caused because facebook dont ask for the user the good informations.

Answer (score 0):

for sdk 4x, you can make use of this

when you start to ask permission make it this way: (since graph api has been upgraded to 2.5 as of now in which email has not been made a default permission)

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile", @"email"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
{
}];
```

and then inside that, continue like

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
             {
                 NSMutableDictionary* parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                 [parameters setValue:@"id, name, email, gender" forKey:@"fields"];

                 [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:parameters]
                  startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
{
// fetch all your datas
}];
```